# regex for preg_match not working

Tags: php, regex

I need to scrape some data from a website. For that I am using preg_match, but I am not able to write the regex for it. The data on the website is

```
title="Russia"/></a>
        <small>*</small> <a href="/profile/roman
```

I have written the regex as `#title=\"Russia\"\/><\/a>((\n|\r)*)<small>*<\/small> <a href=\"/profile/(.+?)\"#sx`

But this is not working and I dont know why ? When I echo my regex it says `#title="Russia"\/><\/a>(( | )*)*<\/small>` . Where are the others gone? And why is it not working ?

Comment: When you echo the regex? Why would you need to echo the regex?

Comment: You are misapplying `*` some regex meta characters. You also enclosed the regex in double quotes, resulting the `\"` to get dropped, and `\r\n` to be transformed into actual cr/newlines. And outputting unescaped `<small>` in the webpage will make it disappear.

Comment: If you're using regex to parse HTML, then you're probably doing something wrong. Why don't you use PHP's DOM Parser instead?

Comment: What exactly you're trying to do by using your regex? Can you show some code?

Comment: @mario: How to apply the * in the correct way. I replaced the " with a ' and now i can see the \n and \r , which i am doing because the input is spread across 2 lines. And please explain the meaning of unescaped <small>.. I am all new to it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#title=\"Russia\"/></a>(\s*)<small>\*</small>\s+<a\s+href=\"/profile/(.+?)\"#sx
```

I have escaped the `*` because its a metacharacter. Without it, you would match strings containing the word `small` followed by zero or more `>`s.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not use regexes to evaluate markup content, especially when you acquire it by scrapping pages.

In your case there are at least three reasons that might be responsible for breaking your regex.

1. Do not attempt to write your own whitespace evaluators when you can simply use `\s` which stands for "any whitespace character"
2. In regular expressions asterisk (*) has a special meaning which is why you can't simply use it to identify asterisks. If you want to collect content inside the small attribute you should use `<small>(.*)</small>` instead. If on the other hand you are actually expecting an asterisk then you have to escape it like this `<small>\*</small>`.
3. Your regex expects a closing quote for your `href` attribute on that last `<a>` but in your sample markup you have none. Provided that on the original page you do have a closing quote the following regex should do the trick.

   `#title=\"Russia\"\/><\/a>(\s*)<small>\*</small> <a href="/profile/(.+)?\"#sx`

However once again I have to advise using a DOM parser like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for this not only because it is much more reliable when handling markup content but also because it can interpret bad markup as well (if its loaded as HTML of course).